# Excel vba spin button fetching wrong time value and data getting changed

Tags: excel, vba, time, format, spin

I created a user form to record data entries on excel. I used 2 frames, 1 for data entry with text boxes, combo boxes. 2nd frame is for listing the data entered. I have created a spin button to cycle through excel data. This data has stating & finishing date & time. While I am able to fetch date in correct format, I am unable to get time in hh:mm format, rather I am getting it in decimal. How to get it. Following spin button Code used

```
Private Sub SpinButton1_Change()
Dim s1, s2
Dim cAdd1 As String
Dim cAdd2 As String

Dim M As VbMsgBoxResult
cAdd1 = "L"
cAdd2 = "AA"

If SpinButton1.Value > 1 Then
s2 = SpinButton1.Value

s1 = "A" & s2
TextBoxEntry.ControlSource = s1

s1 = "B" & s2
ComboBoxOperator.ControlSource = s1

s1 = "C" & s2
TextSales.ControlSource = s1

s1 = "D" & s2
TextCustomer.ControlSource = s1

s1 = "E" & s2
TextJobNo.ControlSource = s1

s1 = "F" & s2
TextTitle.ControlSource = s1

s1 = "G" & s2
TextPagestxt.ControlSource = s1

s1 = "H" & s2
TextPagescvr.ControlSource = s1

s1 = "I" & s2
TextJobsize.ControlSource = s1

s1 = "J" & s2
TextColor.ControlSource = s1

s1 = "K" & s2
ComboBoxDate.ControlSource = s1

's1 = "L" & s2
'ComboBoxTime.ControlSource = s1 ' Giving time in decimal

Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(12, s2).Value = timeValue(ComboBoxTime.Text)  'Data change and circular reference came when back spin

'Range("S1").Value = timeValue(ComboBoxTime.Text)
s1 = "M" & s2
Textsplop.ControlSource = s1

s1 = "N" & s2
ComboBoxStatus.ControlSource = s1

s1 = "O" & s2
TextPPop.ControlSource = s1

s1 = "P" & s2
ComboBoxOPStatus.ControlSource = s1

s1 = "Y" & s2
ComboBoxCorrection.ControlSource = s1

s1 = "Z" & s2
ComboBoxCDate.ControlSource = s1

's1 = "AA" & s2
'ComboBoxCTime.ControlSource = s1 ' Giving time in decimal required in HH:MM

Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(27, s2).Value = timeValue(ComboBoxCTime.Text) 'Complete row data change to time.

s1 = "V" & s2
ComboBoxJobtype.ControlSource = s1
End If
End Sub
```

I used control source to fetch the values but time values returned as decimal.

I tried directly using cell reference but as soon as Spin button used, all row 12 data getting converted to time

[image: Before using Spin Button]

[image: After Using Spin Button]

Comment: Cells require this sequence `Cells(rowindex,columnindex)`

Comment: columnindex value comes from s2 variable, while rowindex, I have assigned 12 & 27 directly

Comment: Pls. L is column and number is row. Means that s2 is row.

Comment: Yes. But when I use spin button., each time the value in the row keeps on changing in excel sheet to time value stored in ComboBoxTime

Comment: Obviously when you click on the spin s2 changes which results that cells(12,s2) will change. Any time you click up the next column will be filled in row 12. Did you try Cells(s2,12)

Comment: Yes, I did try Cells(s2,12). It is filling column 12 with the first data in all rows. What I want to show the data in the combobox for time as it is recorded or stored in excel sheet. ControlSource is working for all other data but not for time. Time is converted into decimal. Is there any way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
ComboBoxCTime.Value = Format(Sheets("Your_sheet_name").Cells(s2,"L"), "hh:mm")
```

Insert the actual sheet name in the code.

For demo try this :

```
Private Sub SpinButton1_Change()
Set r = ActiveSheet.Range("F16:F21")
ReDim b(r.Count, 1)
For i = 0 To r.Count - 1
b(i, 0) = Format(r.Cells(i), "hh:mm")
Next i
ComboBox1.List = b
ComboBox1.Value = Format(ActiveSheet.Cells(15 + SpinButton1.Value, "F"), "hh:mm")
End Sub
```

Add a Spin and a ComboBox to a UserForm.

On a sheet type time values in the Range("F16:F21")

Start the Userform with F5